# Left side of my website not showing bootstrap in xs to lg

Tags: html, css

This is the link to my website. Everything is almost ready except for the left side of the site not showing completely. And I don't know how to change it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Comment: what you expect to see in left side of your website ? tell us the class of the div you don't see,  so that we can see why you can't see it

Comment: the margin-left from the row class is affecting the spacing.

Comment: The class is called: row-no gutter.

Comment: This site aims to build a body of quality questions and answers for *future visitors to have the use of*. An external site doesn't fit that model, as the site could easily change without any record in the question here, making the question and answers loose all context. That's why we require all details to be listed *here*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.row.gutter` gave your page an extra width. Setting `margin: 0;` for `.row.no-gutter` will fix the page view problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `padding: 25px` on box2 as a start to see how you will space it. If you like, use `padding-left: 25px` or so.